# Use Vimeo only for authenticated users?

Tags: php, laravel, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have an Laravel application where users can authenticate.

I uploaded a video to Vimeo and checked "hide video from Vimeo". I also whitelisted my domain. The video can now only be watched if it is embed on my website:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?embedparameter=value" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>.
```

However, how I can make sure that only authorized users may watch it? Currently, anyone who visits my website and knows the url of my private video, could watch it, simply by using the browser-inspector tool and copy/paste an iframe with the url.

Is there a way to ensure that the video is played only when a user is authenticated on my Laravel app (my users have no Vimeo account)?

I would imagine, in order to view a video, I would need to send one request authenticated by OAuth 2.0 that returns a url that will only be valid for the current request, or something like that.

I checked the API but all I found were [instructions](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos) how to make an API call to get basically just the `iframe` html-snippent.

Comment: if vimeo has an api to get the raw video file, i suppose you could just proxy it? maybe [XSendfile](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/xsendfile/)

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo doesn't have a privacy setting that only allows access/playback by specified users, take a look at the available Vimeo video privacy settings here: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Privacy-settings-overview

You'll need to authenticate and verify that the viewer can play/access your videos on your end first, and once you've verified that, get the Vimeo embed code and serve it to the user.